# UTF8 in named.conf bind

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a zone file that looks like this:

```
فلسطين.         172800  IN      NS      idn.pnina.ps.
فلسطين.         172800  IN      NS      ns1.pnina.ps.
فلسطين.         172800  IN      NS      dns1.gov.ps.
فلسطين.         172800  IN      NS      dns3.gov.ps.
```

when trying to load it, it gives me an errors about UTF8.

Is there any way I can force loading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert UTF-8 host- and domain names to the correct [Internationalized Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) in Punycode with for instance the `idn` utility from the libidn package:

```
idn فلسطين 

xn--ygbi2ammx
```

and then use that in your Bind zone:

```
; NS records for فلسطين transcribed in punycode
172800  .xn--ygbi2ammx IN      NS      idn.pnina.ps.
```

Good practice is to include a comment as well (which as far as I know may still be in UTF-8) so you know what host or domain it concerns.

Comment: I noticed this, but the file is generated from another bind server.  
Do you know some good tool for convert that comes by default in CentOS?

Comment: I thought that the libidn package comes from the standard CentOS repository?

Comment: thanks, we fixed it in other way. CentOS lack idn tool that converts whole file - this is what I asked it. Your answer was very helpful, we couldn't do it without it. :)